# Restore main menu editor after disabling it in itself

Tags: settings

I just noticed that the main menu editor on Raspbian allows me to remove the main menu editor from the main menu. But if I removed the main menu editor from the main menu using the main menu editor, I could of course not use the main menu editor anymore to get the main menu editor back into the main menu.

So how would I get it back after disabling it?

Comment: Please enhance your question by adding the OS, hardware, etc.

Comment: Added "On Raspbian". I just assumed that it's the same on all Raspberry Pi models, because I have no info on the others. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the console, the command `alacarte` will start the main menu editor.

If even the console is not available, there's the executable file `/home/pi/.local/share/applications.desktop`, which appears as "Main Menu Editor" e.g. in the PCManFM file browser.

A completely failsafe way, even if the menu is completely destroyed, should be to create a new text file with the `.sh` ending on the desktop, give yourself execution permission in the file's properties, write `alacarte` in it and execute it.